# Libasound2 install problem

Tags: software-installation, raspberry-pi-os

New Raspberry Pi user. Running Raspberry Pi OS, current download, dated 5-27-2020. OS updates are installed before trying to install Libasound2. Using the command "sudo apt-get install git-all libasound2-dev -y".

During the install process a message will appear in the top right corner of the desktop that says "Drive was removed without ejecting, please use menu to eject before removal". After a reboot the system will only boot to a login prompt.

I have tried 3 different Pi boards, which are either a Pi 3B or 3B+, also tried different SD cards, same results.

How can I install Libasound2 without corrupting the system?

Comment: What is the "latest version of Raspian OS"? What is it in one year? Do you mean Raspbian or Raspberry Pi OS? Please specify it exactly.

Comment: It is Raspberry Pi OS, current download, dated 5-27-2020. OS updates are installed before trying to install Libasound2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to install Libasound2 without it corrupting the OS. I omitted `git-all` and `-y`: `sudo apt-get install libasound2-dev`.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.